# Font change in ggplot not working on biplot label names

Tags: r, fonts, ggbiplot

I have stumbled upon a problem, where I can change all the text in a biplot image to the another font, with the exception of labels.

A simple example of the problem is seen below, with label text clearly differing:
[image]

Code that I used is also attached. I cannot find the solution to this issue, hopefully someone can help.

```r
p <- fviz_pca(fit, geom = c("point"), 
              repel = TRUE, label = "var", 
              habillage = IOSDV1$Fertilisation, 
              addEllipses = TRUE, ellipse.type="confidence", 
              palette = "npg", labelsize = 5, pointsize = 3, 
              col.ind = "black", col.var = "black", arrowsize = 0.6) + 
  theme_bw(base_family = "Palatino Linotype") + 
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Palatino Linotype", size = 14)) + 
  labs(title = "")

ggsave(filename = "ggplot_garamond.png", dpi = 600, type = "cairo")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

You have to add the `font.family` argument to `fviz_pca`:

```r
fviz_pca(fit, geom = c("point"), 
         repel = TRUE, label = "var", 
         habillage = IOSDV1$Fertilisation, 
         addEllipses = TRUE, ellipse.type="confidence", 
         palette = "npg", labelsize = 5, pointsize = 3, 
         col.ind = "black", col.var = "black", arrowsize = 0.6,
         font.family = "Palatino Linotype")
```

**Rationale**

Internally, `fviz_pca` calls `fviz`, which in turn calls `ggpubr::ggscatter`. In this function, you can specify the font family with the `font.family` argument.

Comment: Great, that has solved my issue. Many thanks for the help! Best wishes.